# CakePHP setting multiple values into one cookie

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

I know that multiple values can be set to cookie this way:

```
If you want to write more than one value to the cookie at a time,
    you can pass an array:

$this->Cookie->write('User',
    array('name' => 'Larry', 'role' => 'Lead')
);
```

Due to some design issues, I need to set cookie values in different parts of my controller action. But it seems like this minimalized code doesn't work:

```
public function myfunction() {
    $text = "";
    // to be sure that this cookie doesn't exist
    $this->Cookie->delete('mycookie');
    // getting data from cookie, result is NULL
    $data = $this->Cookie->read('mycookie');
    $text .= "data 1 type: ".gettype($data)."<br>";
    $key="mike";
    $value=12;
    // adding key-value to cookie
    $data[$key] = $value;
    // serializing and writing cookie
    $dataS = json_encode($data);
    $this->Cookie->write('mycookie', $dataS, FALSE, '10 days');

    // reading cookie again, but this time result is
    // string {"mike":12} not an array
    $data = $this->Cookie->read('mycookie');
    $text .= "data 2 type: ".gettype($data)."<br>";
    $key="john";
    $value=20;
    // Illegal string offset error for the line below
    $data[$key] = $value;
    $dataS = json_encode($data);
    $this->Cookie->write('mycookie', $dataS, FALSE, '10 days');

    echo $text;

}
```

Page output:

```
Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'john' [APP/Controller/MyController.php, line 2320]  
data 1 type: NULL   
data 2 type: string
```

From the code above, "Mike 12" is set to cookie successfully. But when I read cookie data for the second time, I get a string like this: `{"mike":12}`. Not an array.

When I make `gettype` for "data 2" the output is "string".
So when I make `$data["john"]=20` I get `Illegal string offset error` because `$data` is string not array.

So is it not possible to set same cookie in an action, one by one ?

Edit:
When I create a data array, json_encode that array and write its contents to cookie. Then when in another controller, when I read that cookie contents and assign it so a variable, it is automatically converted to Array.

Comment: You are storing a (JSON) string, why would you expect the component to return something different?

Comment: Because in normal cases, json_encoded strings in the cookies return as Arrays. I get an error when I json_decode it. The error is "it is already Array not a string"

Comment: This would only happen when the data is actually read from the cookie. Without a new request it will read the data stored in the components buffer, which holds the data as is.

Comment: I didn't know there exists a component buffer. I didn't run across in the documents I read..

Answer (score 2):

Encoding and decoding the data in JSON format is an internal functionality of the Coookie component on which your application should not rely! The implementation might change, and your code will break.

Currently decoding of JSON data happens only when the data was actually read from the cookie, which requires a new request. On the same request you would access the original data buffered by the component.

So instead of this JSON thingy you should follow the conventions and pass an array:

```
$data = array();

$key = 'mike';
$value = 12;

$data[$key] = $value;

$this->Cookie->write('mycookie', $data);

// ... do some stuff, and then somewhere else:

$data = $this->Cookie->read('mycookie');

$key = 'john';
$value = 20;

$data[$key] = $value;
$this->Cookie->write('mycookie', $data);
```

or use dot notation (this will result in multiple cookies):

```
$key = 'mike';
$value = 12;
$this->Cookie->write('mycookie.' . $key, $value);

// ... do some stuff, and then somewhere else:

$key = 'john';
$value = 20;
$this->Cookie->write('mycookie.' . $key, $value);
```

See also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#using-the-component

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood my error.. But you mention that Cake's internal functionality can change. So what should I do to be safe for the future releases ? Before writing the cookie I encode the array. When I read cookie I only use CookieComponent's read function and I don't json_decode it. Because result comes as an array. Should I json_decode the output again ? Thanks.

Comment: As shown in the examples, don't encode to JSON at all, instead pass the raw array, the component will take care of it. Alternatively, in case appropriate, use the dot notation style. Both approaches are safe to use, and can be expected not to break until major version changes (like 2.x to 3.x).

Comment: Well, I encode the data because sometimes I add important strings to cookie and they can contain ";" character.

Comment: That's not a problem, the cookie is finally being set using [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) which sends the values in URL encoded format, so chars like `;` are safe to use, even when not using the encrypting functionality of the cookie component.